# table of structs in function argument

Tags: c++

this is my struct:

```
    struct obcyObiekt{
float x;
float y;
bool alive;
};
```

in main i create table of struct

```
obcyObiekt obcy[15];
```

I don't have idea, how add argument of struct table, coz :

```
void initObcych2(struct obcyObiekt &obcy[15] )
```

in main

```
initObcych2(obcy[15]);
std::cout<<obcy[1].x;
```

doesnt work at all :(
there will be always 16 of obcy, so i created table of this

Comment: Change in main `initObcych2(obcy[15]);` to `initObcych2(obcy);`

Comment: If you want 16, why do you allocate 15?

Comment: In C++, a struct is a type, so you can drop the "struct" from declarations or parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the function signature keep the size of the array as part of the type safety:

```
void initObcych2( obcyObiekt (&obcy)[16])
```

This method will only accept an array of `16` elemnts of type `obcyObiekt`, the parameter variable name will be **obcy**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems function initObcych2 is used to initialize elements of array

```
obcyObiekt obcy[15];
```

In this case the function can be declared like

```
void initObcych2( obcyObiekt obcy[], size_t n );
```

and called like

```
initObcych2( obcy, 15 );
```

Or you can declare the function like

```
void initObcych2( obcyObiekt ( &obcy )[15] );
```

and call it like

```
initObcych2( obcy );
```

However the first function declaration is more flexible because you will not need to change the function declaration in case when the size of the array will be changed and it may be called for arrays of different sizes.

As for this record that you showed

```
void initObcych2(struct obcyObiekt &obcy[15] )
```

when

```
struct obcyObiekt &obcy[15]
```

is an array of 15 references to objects of type struct obcyObiekt. C++ does allow to declare arrays of references. It allows to declare a reference to an array like

```
struct obcyObiekt ( &obcy )[15]
```